# call conga composer from APEX

Tags: apex, conga

Does any one know how to call conga composer from APEX?

Tried to follow  [http://knowledge.congasphere.com/congakb/ext/kb69-how-to-call-conga-composer-from-apex?mode=searchresults]

but I get "Your Salesforce session has expired or the Salesforce API Servers are offline. INVALID SESSION ID or SERVER URL"

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Manohar

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're passing the appropriate parameters:

```
Map<String, String> parameters = new Map<String, String> {
    'sessionid' => UserInfo.getSessionId(),
    'serverUrl' => Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/Soap/u/13.0/'+UserInfo.getOrganizationId()
};
```

Include other parameters as appropriate.

Comment: I am using formula fields to pass those paramters as below.. appextremes.com/apps/Conga/PM.aspx?SessionId='; + quote[0].APIgetSessionId__c + '&ServerUrl=' + quote[0].APIServerUrl__c + '&Id=' + quote[0].id

Comment: I don't really see any problem with that, assuming the values are populated, etc. They also mention it may be a problem with locked IP sessions (Setup > Security Controls > Session Settings).

Comment: I tried your approach as well but that didnt help either. or may be I need to use a different approach for my requirement.  thanks for your help Brian.